# how to resolve the Memory Error

Tags: python

This is for my python code

`enter code here`fileName = open(flename,"r")
    dccount = 0
    dcCycles = []
    ccCycles = []
    temp=0
    ccCY = []
    dcCY = []
    for line in fileName:
        length = len(line)
        for i in range(length):
            if i >=4:
                x = line[i-1]
                y = line[i]
                bcValue = x+y
                if bcValue == "IV":
                    ivval = float(int(line[i+2:i+7]))
                    if ivval > 0:
                        if temp == 1:
                            dcCY.append(dcCycles)
                            dcCycles=[]
                            cc = line[dccount:i-5]
                            ccCycles.append(cc)
                            dccount = i
                            temp =0
                        else:
                            cc = line[dccount:i-5]
                            ccCycles.append(cc)
                    else:
                        if temp == 0:
                            ccCY.append(ccCycles)
                            ccCycles=[]
                            dc = line[dccount:i-6]
                            dcCycles.append(dc)
                            dccount = i
                            temp = 1
                        else:
                            dc = line[dccount:i-6]
                            dcCycles.append(dc)

```
fileName.close()
```

in memory error got in ***cc = line[dccount:i-5]*** this ling how to resolve please help me

Comment: Your system ran out of Memory (RAM). Most of the objects you are using are not known to us, so we can hardly say where the memory consumption comes from.

Comment: To avoid getting a memory error, you need to find out what causes the memory consumption. This could either be related to the file being very large compared to your available memory (since you seem to be saving a lot of this file to lists), or you are accidentally creating a lot of objects you do not want containing litte/no additional information.

Comment: Ok thank you for your information i will try

Answer (score 0):

It looks like dccount was not yet defined at that point. You should have gotten a NameError

Comment: He might have defined it earlier in his code, which he has not shown. Nonetheless, I would trust the python traceback if it states that he has a memory error

Comment: Agreed, I realized that when I copied and pasted the code in IDLE. There is a lot of missing info in this question. I don't know how anyone is going to help without knowing the contents of the variables.

Comment: thank you man!!                                                                                   I am already define the dccount value